# Open python program with another python program containing selenium and both are on loop

Tags: python, loops, selenium, infinite-loop

I have two identical python programs first.py and second.py that use selenium and have a long loop. I want first.py to open second.py. I used

```
os.system("python second.py")
```

it started running second.py but then first.py didn't run the code after this line. is this because of the loops? what should I do?

Comment: `os.system` waits for the process to complete.  Take a look at the `subprocess` module in the standard library, which replaces it.  However, if the programs are identical  (why have two if they are the same?) then you stand the risk of a fork bomb.

Comment: Because I need to run both programs simultaneously under two user names like bots talking to eah other.